# Lock screen fragment call in an app

Tags: android, security, android-fragments, android-activity

I already developed a password fragment for my app which needs to be called every time users swaps to another app or (assuming password was created) when the app is called.
Studying some apps with this feature I noticed some of them are slow to call lock screen fragment or previous fragment is called before the lock screen fragment. And some of them are very fast and delivers the fragment fast and correctly. Correctly I mean previous fragment is not shown before the lock fragment.

How can I call the lock screen fragment throughout app? Is inside a callback? Who have to take this kind of control, previous fragment or activity?

Answer (score 0):

After a research on Activity callbacks I solved this way:
Create a private boolean variable loginNow in activity and assign false;
When onStop is called I assign true to it. To guarantee I did the same on onRestart:

```
@Override
public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    loginNow = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    loginNow = true;
}
```

And when onStart is called I verify this boolean and replaces old fragment with my login fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    if( loginNow ){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragment_container, fragment )
                .addToBackStack( null ).commit();
    }
...
}
```